# Why is $x^2=a \pmod{p_1p_2}$ solvable when $x^2=a \pmod {p_i}$ is solvable?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Burton - Number theory
>
> If $x^2=196 \pmod {23}$ and $x^2=196 \pmod{59}$ are solvable, then $x^2=196 \pmod{23\cdot 59}$ is solvable.

Why?

Here, since $\gcd(196,23\cdot 59)=1$, $\overline{196}$ is an element of $\mathbb{Z}_{1357}^X$. Does this imply the statement?

Comment: In your specific example, $196$ is a square already in $\mathbb{Z}$, hence in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ for every $n$.

Comment: Do you know about the Chinese Remainder Theorem?

Comment: Yup. I have proved it :) I will post an answer later (I'm awake for 2days, really exhausted right now)